# Camel - How to get the value from header when setting http4 endpoint?

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel

I would like to get the value of http4 from the header but it throwing me

```
Failed to create route route15 at: >>> To[${header.ExternalEndPoint}]
```

Here is my code

```
.toF("http4://%s", simple("${header.ExternalEndPoint}"))
```

or

```
.toF("http4://%s", constant("${header.ExternalEndPoint}"))
```

It is only working when I hardcoded the value like

```
.toF("http4://localhost/foo");
```

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic URIs in "to"](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) are not supported prior to Camel 2.16. If you're using a version lower than 2.16 then you should use `recipientList`

`.recipientList(simple("http4://${header.ExternalEndPoint}"))`

From 2.16 onwards, `toD` is your friend:

`.toD("http4://${header.ExternalEndPoint}")`